# Help with design of current DAC

Tags: current, dac, nmos, pll, current-sink

I am required to design a current DAC (64 element NMOS) that sinks the current of another current DAC (16 element PMOS).

The specs are as follows:
1. The smallest current output from the PMOS DAC is 6uA.
2. The smallest step size of the NMOS DAC is 6uA/256~25nA (that is the spec I am provided with)

Additional information:
1. The controls to each NMOS element are clocked at a maximum frequency of 15o MHz. (Feedback clock, as this DAC is used to fine tune the frequency of a PLL).

I am having trouble deciding how to bias the NMOS elements to sink 25nA each. I could really use some help, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Here is a sanity check on the DAC goals.

1) update rate is 150Mhz (6 nanoseconds)

2) want settling to 1%

3) need to operate with 25 nanoAnps

4) summing node has 0.1pF total drain capacitance

5) assume the summing node must change the voltage by 0.1 volts, as switch form 1 LSB to 255 LSB.

Given C = 0.1pF and dV/dT = 0.1v/6nS, we use I = C * dV/dT 
and find

I = 1e-13 * 0.1 /6nS = 1e-13 * 1e+9 * 0.1/6 = 1e-4 * 0.016 = 1.6uA

Thus 25nanoA are 64x too slow.

Answer (score 0):

*I am having trouble deciding how to bias the NMOS elements to sink 25nA each.*

25 nA is a very small current, and impractical to create locally using for example an NMOS and a resistor. The resistor will need to have an very high value, for a 2 V drop: 2 V/ 25 nA = 80 Mohm. You don't want that !

What I usually do is use or locally generate a more practical current. If I can make a 1 Mohm resistor I can have around 2 uA for example. That's still a factor 80 too high. But what I can do is make an 80 : 1 current mirror. A current mirror always has mismatch so in practice it is better to do the factor 80 in two steps. For example a 10 : 1 NMOS mirror ( 2uA in, 200 nA out) and feeding the output of that NMOS mirror to a 8 : 1 PMOS mirror (200 nA in, 25 nA out). Then you have your 25 nA.

Like this:

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fssz4s.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Note that here I use standard NMOS/PMOS mirrors. Those are not so accurate. It is just to illustrate what I mean. Of course you can also use better current mirrors with cascodes or local feedback provided you have enough voltage headroom.